# Show related item properties for editing in SharePoint 2013 task form

Tags: 2013, 2010, sharepoint-server, workflow, designer-workflow

Is it possible to show the list item properties of the related item in SharePoint 2013 task form?

So that the users can change the properties and then approve in the same page

I am thinking to add columns in the Task content type and then sync it back to list item after approval, but is there a better way to do this

Please advice, TIA

Answer (score 1):

There is no OOB way to achieve this in SharePoint.

From your description, you want to add columns in the Task content type, however we can't  build relationship between newly created column and related columns' properties.